# Can we integrate selenium code in between Karate UI code?

Tags: karate

Can we integrate selenium code in between Karate UI code ?
As we have some gap in Karate UI , can we use selenium code in between to suffice our requirement ?

Comment: based on the quality of your questions, I recommend that you just use selenium. you will love it 

Answer (score 0):

No, please just switch to Selenium. Ideally we would like people to contribute so that gaps in Karate are closed, but I guess that is not possible in this case.

And as explained in other answers - most likely the right answer is to use JS code where needed to do advanced operations.